# How do I link/navigate a application bar icon to a new WP page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, application-bar

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm in the process of learning WP7 development, I'm struggling with one thing.

How can I link an application bar icon to a new WP7 page in the same solution.

I know where to find the icons (prog files>x86>SDK>7.1>Icons) and how to move them to the icon directory in the solution explorer, just want to know how I can actually link it to a page.

Hope you can help, I understand this may be a silly question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Icon-format in XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="NavigateButtonClick" IconUri="/Images/image.png" Text="go" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

And the code:

```
private void NavigateButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define the handler for the Click event on the icon (in XAML this will be something like `Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"`) You need to fire a Navigation command, similar to the following...

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyNewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

where `/MyNewPage.xaml` is the relative path to the page you want to visit.